# Zend framework 2 form select element set required false

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2

I have a select element as follows and I want to make it non required field. But I am unable to do so. It gives me error "Value is required and can't be empty"

```
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'civil_status',
            'type' => 'Select',
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'civil_status',
                'class' => 'form-control',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'empty_option' => 'Civil status',
                'value_options' => array(
                    'married' => 'Married',
                    'single' => 'Single',
                    'other' => 'other',
                ),
            )
        ));
```

I have set the validation as follows

```
            $this->inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                        'name' => 'civil_status',
                        'required' => FALSE,
                        'allow_empty' => TRUE,
                        'filters' => array(
                            array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                        ),
                        'validators' => array(
                            array(
                                'name' => 'StringLength',
                                'options' => array(
                                    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                                    'min' => '2',
                                    'max' => '255',
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
            )));
```

I tried to remove required from input filter as above and even more I have tried to remove required validation from the controller too as follows. But nothing seams to work. Please let me know if you guys know to fix this issue.

```
            $form->getInputFilter()->get("civil_status")->setRequired(FALSE);
            $form->getInputFilter()->get("civil_status")->setAllowEmpty(TRUE);
```

Comment: Try to remove the validator ?

Comment: @RemiThomas Can you show me the way ?

Comment: You can remove into your array of your inputFilter. Or like this way $form->getInputFilter()->get("civil_status")->remove("StringLength");

Comment: Note that getInputFilter is lazyloaded and should always be called last. If you add another input to the set, and have called getInputfilter _before_ that - you won't find the new one.

Answer (score 2):

Select has build in InArray validator you dont need to use StringLength here or filters you only need to use 'required' => false which should work.

```
$this->inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                    'name' => 'civil_status',
                    'required' => false,
        )));
```

I know it might be strange question but did you add your InputFilter to your Form before you hit $form->IsValid() ?